# Python re finding string between underscore and ext

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
"1206292WS_R0_ws.shp"
```

I am trying to re.sub everything except what is between the second "_" and ".shp"

Output would be "ws" in this case.

I have managed to remove the .shp but for the life of me cannot figure out how to get rid of everything before the "_"

```
epass = "1206292WS_R0_ws.shp"

regex = re.compile(r"(\.shp$)")

x = re.sub(regex, "", epass)
```

Outputs

```
1206292WS_R0_ws
```

Desired output:

```
ws
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you dont really need a regex for this

```
print epass.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]


>>> timeit.timeit("epass.split(\"_\")[-1].split(\".\")[0]",setup="from __main__
import epass")
0.57268652953933608

>>> timeit.timeit("regex.findall(epass)",setup="from __main__ import epass,regex
0.59134766185007948
```

speed seems very similar for both but a tiny bit faster with splits

actually **by far the fastest method** is

```
print epass.rsplit("_",1)[-1].split(".")[0]
```

which takes 3 seconds on a string 100k long (on my system) vs 35+ seconds for either of the other methods

If you actually mean the second _ and not the last _ then you could do it

```
epass.split("_",2)[-1].split(".")
```

although depending on where the 2nd _ is a regex may be just as fast or faster

Comment: If when the OP says second _ he means the last then this would be the way to go, if he really means second this won't work for strings where the number of _ is not equal 2.

Comment: good point ... I assumed he meant last ... if not then that changes stuff

Comment: My bad on not being specific. I mean the last "_"

Comment: It might be faster to use `rsplit` since he only cares about the final one. `epass.rsplit('_', 1)[1]` **EDIT** I just noticed that your "by far fastest" method uses rsplit already ;)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you describe is  `^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)[.]shp$`

```
>>> import re
>>> s="1206292WS_R0_ws.shp"
>>> regex=re.compile(r"^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)[.]shp$")
>>> x=re.sub(regex,r"\1",s)
>>> print x
ws
```

Note: this is the regular expression as you describe it, not necessarily the best way to solve the actual problem.

> everything except what is between the second "_" and ".shp"

Regexplation:

```
^       # Start of the string
[^_]*   # Any string of characters not containing _
_       # Literal 
[^_]*   # Any string of characters not containing _
(       # Start capture group
.*      # Anything
)       # Close capture group
[.]shp  # Literal .shp
$       # End of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you dont want regex,you can use the rfind and find method

```
epass[epass.rfind('_')+1:epass.find('.')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `_([^_]+)\.shp$` will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Simple version with RE

```
   import re
    re_f=re.compile('^.*_')
    re_b=re.compile('\..*')
    inp = "1206292WS_R0_ws.shp"
    out = re_f.sub('',inp)
    out = re_b.sub('',out)
    print out
    ws
```